# Go into recovery mode in Sony Live With Walkman

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, recovery-mode

Does anyone know how to get into recovery mode for Sony Live With Walkman phone?

***These key combination not working***

1. Volume Up / Down
2. Volume Up / Down + Power Button
3. Power Button + Home button

Is there something I'm missing? I am finding solution for this question, [Sony Live With The Walkman : Phone is restarting continuously](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49096/29300)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use any custom kernel or do you have stock factory default?
IF you don't have stock then there is no recovery.
If you have a custom kernel, you should press the VOL DOWN button when you see the KERNEL logo. That's because custom kernels have CWM recovery integrated, because Xperia 2011 phones don't have a the *recovery* partition.

For solution to your problem, you should use SEUS, that's the only way to fix a bootloop with stock kernel.
You can download it from here: http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/update-service/
The software is self-explanatory and will guide you how to enter into flash mode.
Here's a tutorial on how to use SEUS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_OCgB6ASqQ

Answer (score 0):

Is your boot-loader unlocked via [Sony unlocking tool](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/unlock-bootloader/)?

*Caveat Emptor* You will lose data **proceeding** below!

Quoted directly:

> What phones can be unlocked?
>
> To check if you phone can be unlocked, follow the steps below:
>
> - First, you should confirm that it is possible to unlock the boot loader of your phone by checking the service menu. In your phone, open
>     the dialler and enter *#*#7378423#*#* to access the service menu.
> - In your phone, tap Service info > Configuration > Rooting Status. If Bootloader unlock allowed says Yes, then you can continue with the
>     next step. If it says No, or if the status is missing, your device
>     cannot be unlocked.

If the above says it cannot be unlocked, then you cannot unlock it and flash a custom ROM, you're out of luck! Follow the answer below by another poster who is 100% correct in usage of SUS (see below further down in my answer) to reset it.

If it says it can, then go ahead and follow the instructions to unlock the boot-loader. You will lose your settings.

Then go to XDA and install [LegacyXperia](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2227517) which has the custom ClockWorkMod Recovery which can be activated by toggling the volume buttons upon start-up.

The quirk about the SEMC 2011 line of handsets is - there's no actual recovery partition, the custom boot image found within LegacyXperia handles the necessary loading of the recovery if the volume keys are pressed, and if not, continues loading Android as usual.

Oh and by the way, you might notice on some websites, where it governs using `fastboot`, it will say something like this: `fastboot flash boot boot.img` - **that** is incorrect!

You *must* specify `fastboot -i 0xfce flash boot boot.img`, its the `-i 0xfce` part that is omitted. It will not work without it.

If you wish to use a more powerful tool unlike SUS tool (Sony companion tool that checks for firmware updates), you can use this tool called [Flashtool](http://androxyde.github.io/) which can do a lot more than the SUS software itself, such as re-locking the boot-loader (if reverting back to stock).

The above is for the more adventurous kind of person, if not the other answer by the poster is more suited.